# GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation

Tags: php, xampp

disculpen alguien que me pueda ayudar a como instalar esa libreria? es que no busco el archivo php.ini[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo estás en windows. para encontrar el php.ini puedes hacerlo ejecutando desde la terminal (linea de comandos) el comando

```
php --ini
```

El resultado será algo como lo que sigue

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\PR01-base> php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

en C:\xampp\php\php.ini encontrarás el php buscado.

Para instalar la librería GD, solo hay que descomentar (sacar el ;) de la linea siguiente
`extension=gd2`

Ojala esta info te sume.